# Store objects onto a predefined array

Tags: javascript, dynamic-arrays

I know this can be achieved by using the push method, however for the sake of ordering I am unable to use it.

```
  //first create empty array, and define size of it
            for (var t = 0; t < pics.length; t++) {


                if(pics.length>3 && t<3)
                {
                addImageViews.push(" ");


                }


                }
```

Later on in my code, I want to replace these default values with objects:

```
        if(t==0){

//clear element in that index                                                   

        addImageViews[0] = null;
//replace with object

        addImageViews[0] = img;
        }else if(t==1){

        addImageViews[1] = null;    
        addImageViews[1] = img;

        }else if(t==2){

        addImageViews[2] =null; 
        addImageViews[2] = img; 


    }
```

Output of addImageViews:

```
[INFO] :   (
[INFO] :       "[object TiUIImageView]",
[INFO] :       "[object TiUIImageView]",
[INFO] :       "[object TiUIImageView]"
[INFO] :   )
```

I suspect that it has stored each object as a string, rather then an object (it's original form).

Why is this happening, what is the best way to avoid this?

Thanks.

Comment: if img is an object, it should be working fine

Comment: You don't need to define the size of an array, simply start using it it. Also try debuggin your code with the console. That output looks like alert, which stringifies everything.

Comment: in this case i had to , because it would push the objects onto the array in the wrong order - async method messing up the t value. 0,2,1 instead of 0,1,2

Comment: Looks like my code is correct, it is just not accepting the new array into the scrollableview widget in titanium (but would accept it , if I used pure push)

Answer (score 0):

Code in the original post was correct, the problem was in another part of the code.